# From discrete transfer function to state space model

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-time

I have been trying to make state space model from discrete function typed bellow. I have tried to solve it in many ways, but was unable to find appropriate model. What I have is this discrete funcion of a system:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq1}
y(k) = a_1 \cdot y(k-1) + a_2\cdot y(k-2) + b \cdot u(k-1) + r
\end{equation}

I would like to make description of the same system in state space. I need it in discrete form, because I need to implement it later for predictive regulator.

What I done so far is the following:

I wrote down two rules:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq3}
 \begin{array}{l}
x_1(k+1) = x_2(k) \\
x_2(k+1) = y(k+2)
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

I considered the second rule in system equation (first equation):
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq44}
x_2(k+1) =  a_1x_2(k) +a_2x_2(k-1)+bu(k+1)+r 
\end{equation}

I considered the first rule in system equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq4}
x_2(k+1) =   a_1x_2(k) +a_2x_1(k)+bu(k+1)+r
\end{equation}

Than I wrote again the two equations which I would like to write in form of state space:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq5}
\begin{array}{l}
x_1(k+1) =  x_2(k) \\
x_2(k+1) =   a_1x_2(k) +a_2x_1(k)+bu(k+1)+r
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Then I wrote them in matrix form:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq6}
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k+1) \\  
x_2(k+1)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0& 1 \\  
a_1& a_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k) \\  
x_2(k)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  
b 
\end{bmatrix}u(k+1)
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  
r
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

At the end I figured out that I would also need to change u(k+1) to u(k), but was unable to do so. Can anyone suggest me how can I repair that?

So to summorize the system equation in matrix form should look something like this:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq7}
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k+1) \\  
x_2(k+1)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0& 1 \\  
a_1& a_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k) \\  
x_2(k)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  
b 
\end{bmatrix}u(k)
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\  
r
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The system is almost already in state-space form :)
Let $x_1(k) = y(k)$ and $x_2(k) = y(k-1)$, then
$$x_1(k) = a_1 x_1(k-1) + a_2 x_2(k-1) +b u(k-1) +r,$$
to which you add
$$ x_2(k) = x_1(k-1).$$

And you get the system you want
$$ \left[ x_1(k) \atop x_2(k) \right ] = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \left[ x_1(k-1) \atop x_2(k-1)\right] + \left[ b \atop 0 \right]u(k-1) + \left[r \atop 0 \right],$$
together with the observation equation
$$y(k) = \left[1 \; 0\right]\left[x_1(k)\atop x_2(k)\right].$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you, this is correct, but how can I then use this set of matrices for calculation of output in next step. I would like to get something like this:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq50}
y(k+1) = x_2(k) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \quad 
1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(k) \\  
x_2(k)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I need to extract state space matrices, because I need to construct PFC regulator.

Comment: You are correct, in my model the output is the first state component. I have added the output equation.